# MSSQL Transactional Replication

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, database-replication, transactional-replication

I have an application that almost continuously works with inserting or updating data. Since multiple requests are handled asynchronous I wrote my queries like below. I used an example based on SO, but that's not what I'm actually doing.

```
DECLARE @rows int;
INSERT INTO [user] ([username],[reputation])
SELECT [username],[reputation]
FROM (
    SELECT [username]=:user,[reputation]=:rep
) A
WHERE A.[username] NOT IN (
  SELECT [username]
  FROM [user]
);
SET @rows = @@ROWCOUNT;

IF (@rows=0) BEGIN
  UPDATE [user]
  SET [reputation]=:rep, [updated]=GetDate()
  WHERE [username]=:user
END;
```

This is passed in total to the database with `PHP` `PDO`. Because of the amount of data and other processing factors it's heavy on the (cheap) VPS it's running on. It's not really a problem if these processes run slow or get delayed, but on the other hand this data should be available via a website and then the queries on the data should be quick.

I was thinking about replicating parts of the processed data to a second server and running the website on that database. But I'm wondering how that would actually work with a query like above.

I'm guessing the `UPDATE` query will only be in the transaction log when `@rows=0`, so that won't be a problem.

But would the first part only send `INSERT INTO [user] ([username],[reputation]) VALUES ('Hugo Delsing', '10k')` or the entire query with the `WHERE NOT IN ()` query?

Most of the time a user would exists, so if it only runs the new inserts that won't be a problem. But if it would run the entire query each time the benefits would be small.

Obviously I could wrap the first part up in another check `if exists(select 1 from [user] where [username] = :user)` to make sure it only runs when there is no user, but I'm wondering if that is necessary.

Bonus question, but feel free to ignore because it's a bit broad: Would replicating be the way to go or does `MS SQL` offer other/better solutions for something like this?